# can not Load project workspace Integrity error in xcode 5.1.1?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, xcode-workspace

In xcode 5.1.1 i have copy one project from one pc to another.and run it.it shows error like this.[image]

[image]

when i click upon red block it shows like popup above

Comment: This usually happens to me when merging project files go wrong. I have to re-check the syntax of ```.pbxproj``` and make sure everything's fine. There isn't a lint for ```pbxproj``` yet, so, if you have the file versioned, I'll advice you to checkout an older version an try again.

Comment: but i haven't merge two project.just copied. still not find any solution

Comment: Could you find a solution? Having the same trouble and cannot fix. There is no guidance for that error on net, only I found this queston.

Comment: @KutayDemireren Sorry ,but still nothing